# Automatically updating user-edited features in QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, vector, editing

I am working on a plugin for QGIS (2.12).  It uses data stored in an Spatialite database.  When the user creates a new feature, the plugin should:

- update the feature attribute table (the popup form is disabled)
- update another (non-geometry) table in the database
- if the polygon overlaps any existing polygons:

  - update the polygon geometry using the difference method

The modifications do not need any user input, and can happen in 'real-time' or following a commitChanges(), but the user should remain in (or be returned to) an editing session.

What is the best strategy for this? Should I use the provider, the vector layer functions, the iface.vectorLayerTools?

---

So far, I have not had much success.  I have a class that is created on the layer.editingStarted() signal that listens for changes to geometry.  It includes the following:

```
def __init__(self, iface, vlayer, db):
    self.vlayer = vlayer
    self.edit_buffer = vlayer.editBuffer()

def connect_signals
    self.edit_buffer.featureAdded.connect(self.feature_added)
    self.edit_buffer.geometryChanged.connect(self.geometry_changed)
    self.vlayer.beforeCommitChanges.connect(self.disconnect_eb_signals)
    self.vlayer.committedFeaturesAdded.connect(self.committed_add)
```

I first tried to use the edit buffer's `featureAdded()` signal e.g.

```
def feature_added(self, fid):
    self.vlayer.beginEditCommand('Update attributes')
    self.vlayer.changeAttributeValue(fid, 1, 'new_value')
    self.vlayer.endEditCommand()
```

Using the temporary fids given to the pre-commit features prevented making the changes to the other tables, which needed to reference them.  Also, this method caused QGIS to crash/segmentation fault if the Undo command was used (on Linux, and with Undo, Redo on Windows).

Is this a bug, or am I just approaching this in the wrong way?

I have also tried using the `commitedFeaturesAdded()` signal.  This solved the undo/redo issues and allowed me to update the attribute table directly in the database via SQL commands, after the feature was created with the final fid.  However, now when I try to change the geometry and check for intersection/overlap again I get stuck in a loop of newly committed features.

Finally, I tried calculating the modified geometry, exporting as Wkt and using GeomFromText to update the `vlayer` table directly.  In this case, the SQL is run without error, but the geometry doesn't seem to be updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a way to do this.  Changes to the feature geometry (e.g. removing overlaps) and attributes are made to committed new features, only after the `committedFeaturesAdded` signal has fired.  Signals from the EditBuffer can be used to trigger messages but not database changes.

Where modifications fail, it is easier to delete the user feature and add a new one with the modified values.

I have posted code below that form a working example.

```
"""minimum worked example for changing attributes and geometries.  
to test, set appropriate database and layer names then save as
feature_modifier.py.  You can then type
`import feature_modifier as fm` into console, then run
`fm = feature_modifier.FeatureModifier()`.  
Begin editing and watch signals fire."""

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *


class FeatureModifier(object):
    """Modifies features automatically when user edits are saved."""
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.load_layer()
        self.connect_signals()

    def load_layer(self):
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        db_path = '/path/to/database.sqlite'
        uri.setDatabase(db_path)
        uri.setDataSource('', 'mylayer', 'geometry')
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'mylayer', 'spatialite')
        vlayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(27700,
                      QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId), False)
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
        self.vlayer = vlayer

    def connect_signals(self):
        self.vlayer.editingStarted.connect(self.editing_started)
        self.vlayer.editingStopped.connect(self.editing_stopped)

    def editing_started(self):
        print('Editing started')
        # Disable attributes dialog
        QSettings().setValue(
            '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', True)
        self.edit_handler = EditHandler(self.vlayer)

    def editing_stopped(self):
        print('Editing stopped')
        self.edit_handler = None
        # Re-enable attributes dialog
        QSettings().setValue(
            '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', False)
        if self.vlayer.isEditable() is True:
            # Rolling back changes ends destroys geometry_handler class but
            # layer remains editable.  In this case, recreate it.
            self.editing_started()

    def clean_up(self):
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(self.vlayer.id())
        self.iface.mapCanvas().clearCache()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()


class EditHandler(object):
    """
    Listens for committed feature additions and changes feature attributes.
    """
    def __init__(self, vlayer):
        self.vlayer = vlayer
        self.connect_committed_signals()

    def connect_committed_signals(self):
        """
        Connect signals for editing events
        """
        self.vlayer.committedFeaturesAdded.connect(self.committed_adds)
        self.vlayer.committedGeometriesChanges.connect(self.committed_changes)
        self.vlayer.committedFeaturesRemoved.connect(self.committed_deletes)

    def disconnect_committed_signals(self):
        """
        Disconnect signals for editing events
        """
        self.vlayer.committedFeaturesAdded.disconnect()
        self.vlayer.committedGeometriesChanges.disconnect()
        self.vlayer.committedFeaturesRemoved.disconnect()

    def committed_adds(self, layer_id, added_features):
        print('Committed features added to layer {}:'.format(layer_id))
        for feature in added_features:
            print(feature.id())
            self.replace_feature(feature.id())

    def committed_changes(self, layer_id, changed_geometries):
        print('Committed geometries changed in layer {}:'.format(layer_id))
        for fid in changed_geometries.keys():
            print(fid)
            self.update_geometry(fid, changed_geometries[fid])

    def committed_deletes(self, layer_id, deleted_fids):
        print('Committed features deleted from layer {}:'.format(layer_id))
        for fid in deleted_fids:
            print(fid)

    def replace_feature(self, fid):
        """
        Replace feature with customised geometry and attributes.
        """
        print('Replacing feature {} here.'.format(fid))
        feature = self.vlayer.getFeatures(
            QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(fid)).next()
        geometry = feature.geometry()

        # Create new feature
        new_feature = QgsFeature(self.vlayer.pendingFields())
        geometry.translate(0, 50)  # Modify original geometry
        new_feature.setGeometry(geometry)
        new_feature.setAttribute('symbol', 10)  # Customise attributes

        # Update layer by removing old and adding new
        result = self.vlayer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures([fid])
        result, new_features = self.vlayer.dataProvider().addFeatures(
                [new_feature])
        for f in new_features:
            print('Replacement feature {} added'.format(f.id()))

    def update_geometry(self, fid, geometry):
        """
        Update the geometry of a feature, e.g. jump 100 m east.
        """
        geometry.translate(100, 0)
        self.vlayer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({fid: geometry})
```

Comment: +1 I'm toal newbie in python, but tested the example and it is that what I was searching for. Thank you for sharing your experiences. Only thing is I have to call 'fm.FeatureModifier(iface)' but everything else worked fine!